# Why is my Class found in controller but not in model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

--Please disregard, I have solved the problem; see below --
I have code in a controller for using Nexmo and it works fine in that controller where the namespace is "App\Http\Controllers".

`$basic = new Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');`

However, I decided to refactor and put this code into a model where the namespace is just "App".
Now I get a "Class not Found" error on this line. I am guessing that the problem is due to a misunderstanding on my part of namespaces or pathing.

Comment: please, share controller and model

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `\` in front of the namespace, the compiler will start looking from the current namespace.

So, either add an `\` in front of the class name or include the namespace at the top of your PHP file.

```
$basic = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
//           ^ here
```

The reason this worked in your controller is probably because you have an include for `Nexmo` at the top of your PHP file.

Comment: If I add the ```\``` as you suggest, the error simply changes to "Class Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic Not Found" as opposed to "Class App\Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic Not Found".

I do not have an include for Nexmo in the controller PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `use Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic` above the class declaration and then just doing `$basic = new Basic('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');` in the Model?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am feeling silly. I had git reverted to remove a Laravel package I had installed but didn't want and I went back too far and removed the Nexmo client install as well, which obviously explains why the Class wasn't found. I reinstalled the Nexmo package and... voila! It works.
I apologize for wasting people's time.